# How to convert byte[] to String correctly?

Tags: java, string, byte, type-conversion

I'm building a `swing` interface in Java, I build a `middleware` which keeps reading the serial port and saving what's coming to `String`, here it's how I'm doing this:

```
public class RFID {
  private static RFIDReader rReader;
  private static boolean state;

  public RFID(RFIDReader rReader) {
    this.rReader = rReader;
    this.state = true;
  }

  public void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    } else {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);

        if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            //(new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
        }
    }
}

public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {

    InputStream in;

    public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        String code;
        try {
            while (state == true && (len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                code = new String(buffer, 0, len);
                if (code.length() > 1)
                    rReader.setCode(code);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void finish(){
    state = false;
}

public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {

    OutputStream out;

    public SerialWriter(OutputStream out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = System.in.read()) > -1) {
                this.out.write(c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So when I try to print what `code` is storing, it shows like this:

```
AC000F9
3
BB
```

What actually should look like this:

```
AC000F93BB
```

What am I doing wrong here ? This conversion from `byte[]` to `String` is not right ?

**EDIT:**
I need to read a string with 10 characters at total.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where 'code' is assembled.  Read the value of len.

Comment: ..or, to put it another way, why should it look like 'AC000F93BB'? Why should read() not return after it has got the first 7 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use an `InputStream` to read from - use a `Reader` of some description. If you *need* to start with an `InputStream`, wrap it in an `InputStreamReader`. I would change your constructor to accept a `Reader` though, and allow clients to pass whatever reader they want in. That will make it easier to test (as you can just use a `StringReader`).

EDIT: Note - if you *do* need to create a reader from a binary `InputStream`, be explicit in your choice of `Charset` (encoding). So use the `InputStreamReader` constructor overload which specifies one. Even if you want to use the platform default, I'd be explicit about that to make it clear what you're doing.

EDIT: Beyond "where the string conversion happens" it's unclear what you're expecting to read. You're dealing with streaming APIs - what determines how much you really want to read before calling `setCode`? Is it a whole line? Is it some fixed number of characters? Is it characters before a particular delimiter?

EDIT: Now we know a bit more, I suggest you write a helper method like this:

```
// Assuming you now have a field of type Reader, called reader
private String readEntry() throws IOException {
    char[] buffer = new char[10];
    int index = 0;
    while (index < buffer.length) {
        int charsRead = reader.read(buffer, index, buffer.length - index);
        if (charsRead == -1) {
            throw new IOException("Couldn't read entry - end of data");
        }
        index += charsRead;
    }
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: I'd also add: *choose a `Charset`*.  That's the only way to be sure of your conversion between `byte[]` and `String`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you for your help.
I'm new with Java, so I put my class so you guys could look what it's really happening.

I'm expecting to read a string with 10 characters at total.
It's a fixed number of characters, always 10, there's no particular delimiter, the `SERIAL_PORT` library already take care of that, but that's just this annoying problem wich we are discussing here.

Comment: @ValterHenrique: Okay, if you always want to read 10 characters, you'll need to loop through reading "an amount" until you've got 10. Will edit.

Comment: @ValterHenrique: Have a look now.

Comment: @JonSkeet I still don't know how to initialize the `reader`, because I need to start with an `InputStream` because the `serialPort` object have only `serialPort.getInputStream()` which returns an `InputStream`.
So I try to wrap with `InputStreamReader` but this class don't return a `Reader` object tough.

Comment: @ValterHenrique: Yes it does - `InputStreamReader` *is* a `Reader` (it extends `Reader`).